# Dropping filename extensions with find -exec

Tags: command-line, find, filenames

When using `find`, how can I drop the original filename extension (i.e. `.pdf`) from the second pair of `-exec` braces (`{}`)?

---

**For example:**

```
find ~/Documents -regex 'LOGIC.*\.pdf' -exec pdf2svg {} {}.svg \;
```

---

**Input filename:**

```
~/Documents/LOGIC-P_OR_Q.pdf
```

**Output filename:**

```
~/Documents/LOGIC-P_OR_Q.pdf.svg
```

**Desired filename:**

```
~/Documents/LOGIC-P_OR_Q.svg
```

Comment: It would be better to use `-name "LOGIC*.pdf"` to match the filename as `-regex` matches against the full pathname.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an "in-line" shell script, and [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

```
-exec sh -c 'pdf2svg "$1" "${1%.pdf}.svg"' sh {} \;
```

or (more efficiently, if your `find` supports it)

```
-exec sh -c 'for f; do pdf2svg "$f" "${f%.pdf}.svg"; done' sh {} +
```

Comment: `-exec ... {} +` is standard syntax, so it _ought_ to be supported.

Answer (score -1):

One method would be to run the results through a basic script -

```
for i in $( find ~/Documents -regex 'LOGIC.*\.pdf' )  
do  
    o=$( echo $i | sed -e s/.pdf$// )  
    pdf2svg $i ${o}.svg  
done
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697